# How to display a linked to section beneath a Bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

How do I display a "linked to" section beneath a Bootstrap navbar?

I am using the latest version of `Twitter Bootstrap`, namely `3.03` together with `ASP.NET MVC 5`.

I have a navbar at the top of my page and my markup for this navbar looks like this:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               @Html.ActionLink("Brendan Vogt", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="@(Model.Equals("home") ? "active" : "")">
                         <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home
                         </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="@(Model.Equals("about") ? "active" : "")">
                         @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
                    </li>
               </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
</header>
```

I have the following in my css file:

```
body
{
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Here is the markup on my about page:

```
<div class="container">
     <h1>About My Website</h1>
     <p>This is my <a href="#test-link">Test Link</a>.<p>
     <h2 id="test-link">About Test Link</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on Test Link I need it to go to the h2 header that says About Test Link, which is on the same page but just a bit further down, and then I need this h2 header to be visible at the top of the page.  Currently when I click on Test Link the h2 header is at the top of the page but behind the navbar.  How do I get it to display beneath the navbar like with my h1 header About My Website when the page loads up for the first time?

Comment: mmm....may b giving a fiddle would be more helpful.....

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are going through. If you want your h2 header to display just beneath the navbar like your h1 header when someone clicks on the test link, you will have to subtract 60px from the total amount of scroll. And this is not possible with CSS, I guess. So, here's the jQuery solution for you:

```
$("a[href*=#]").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top - 60 + "px"
    });
    return false;
});
```

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vLu3K/)**

If you want more space, then just increase the value from 60 to anything you want. Also, I did't specify the exact id because I am assuming that there might be other links too for which you need the same effect. This way, you are safe and you don't have to hard code the id each time you want the same effect for other links.

Comment: Have you actually tested this?

Comment: Ok. Please wait a min.

Comment: @Morpheus I have updated my answer with the working example on JS Fiddle now.

Comment: I understand it's working with non-bootstrap html/css. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/UXMbB/

Comment: You didn't add much content for it come on the top. It just can't have blank space on the bottom, right? I updated your fiddle and it's working pretty well. Have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/UXMbB/1/
With bootstrap or non-bootstrap, it wil be the same.

Comment: Have a cup of coffee :)